# Reload the DataGridView when changes occur to its dataset vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a DataGridView control in my windows form application. What i want to do is this: 
I want to reload the view so that it shows the correct data when a change occur to the database table that it is bound.
In other words, when i delete a record, using an sql query not the DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow) property, i want the changes to occur to the datagridview also.
For example: I have a customers table that is bound to the datagridview. When i delete a record, lets say the one with ID=5, i want the row to be removed from the gridview in run-time. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

I am calling this procedure every time i delete a customer in order to re-bind the datasource

```
Private Sub reloadDataset()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
        DataGridView1.DataSource = CustomerBindingSource
    End Sub
```

It does not work though....What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for your effort..

**EDIT 2**

Just to clarify: CustomerBindingSource has DataSource(myDatasource) and datamember the table customers

Comment: In order to reflect the changes you need to bind the collection back to grid when changes are made . Please show ur code which u have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell from the limited code you have posted, but if you are using a BindingSource you need to make sure you are reloading it's DataSource, not the DataGridView DataSource.  The DataGridView can stay bound to the same BindingSource:

```
Private Sub Load()

   'Tell DataGridView to use BindingSource.
    DataGridView1.DataSource = CustomerBindingSource

   'Fetch the table.
   'Tell the BindingSource what you want it to wrap/use as it's DataSource.
   CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = FetchData()

End Sub

Private Sub Reload()

   'We have made some changes and need to refresh/reload.
   'We need to re-fetch the table and re-bind it to BindingSource's DataSource.
   CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = FetchData()

End Sub

Private Function FetchData() as DataTable

     Using Conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("connectionString"),
        Command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SQLQuery", Conn),
        Adapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(Command)

        Dim Table As New DataTable

        Adapter.Fill(Table)

        Return Table

    End Using

End Function
```

FetchData returns a datatable that the BindingSource can bind to, but you could return any object that can be bound.  Note that this implementation of FetchData is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Casey Wilkins. So if i get this right you suggest i create a DataTable which will populate with data from the database. The sub load() will be my form_load(). I then make the changes to the table in the database (delete, add customers) and then i rebind the DataTable as NewTableData by calling the sub Reload()?

Comment: In essence, yes.  The key is to make sure you a) reload the DataTable with the changed data and b) rebind the new DataTable to the BindingSource.  I'll update my answer shortly with some more code to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much Casey. The logic i used is the same as urs only that i used DataReader for the data-fetching! Thanks again for your help